# Is there a way to find the 'inner text' of elements that change dynamically in Python using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So basically this is what I want to achieve.
[image:1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlZos.png) I want the inner texts (in this case 16 and 23) of the divs. The values of these divs keep on changing dynamically. [image:2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KI9CT.png) As you can see the numbers inside the divs have dynamically changed. So basically I want to save all of these values. ie. the inner texts of both the divs for each time the divs change dynamically.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you show some code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
mydivA=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='a']")
print(mydivA.text)

mydivB=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='b']")
print(mydivB.text)
```